# How to manage saved login info in SSMS login dialog?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) has saved 3 login information on my computer. However, when I tell it to remeber the 4th login info, it simply won't remember anything next time.

[image]

This means that each and every time I want to connect using that Login, I should provide user name and password, and this really sucks.

Do you know how can we manage saved login information of the login Dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I filed a bug about this issue, that we can't manage that MRU list:

[SSMS : Expose "Connect to Server" MRU list to users](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=424800)

They've fixed the issue where you had to either deal with the list you have or purge the entire thing by deleting mru.dat or SqlStudio.bin. But they haven't really made the list any more manageable. I've asked the author of a popular free add-in about extending his tool to support this functionality and he's potentially going to look into it.

In the meantime, if you really want to have many (most complain about the opposite, too many redundant entries in the list), you should just create four different registered servers, and connect to them from the Registered Servers node in Management Studio. This is much easier than trying to identify *which* 127.0.0.1 credentials you want to connect to - much easier to name your registered servers 127.0.0.1/login-name for much quicker recognition.

If you want to be able to identify a server and login by server name alone, then maybe you could add entries to your hosts files that all point to 127.0.0.1, but look like 'local.login1' and 'local.login2'... you should be able to save each of these connection entries separately because Management Studio will treat them all as different servers, even if they ultimately point to the same instance of SQL Server.